# How to retrieve function parameters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, pdb-files, intellitrace

I used standalone collector to gather traces from a production system using standalone collector and default collection_plan.ASP.NET.trace.xml  plan. When I open the trace file, using Visual Studio 2015, I can see certain excpetions thrown from my code but don't see any function parameters in the locals/auto windows. I make sure to have the correct version of pdb files and its path is setup correctly in VS. How can I get the details about function parameters?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliTrace historical debugger does not collect/record values of local variables. As far as I know the reason behind that is performance. In other words, if IntelliTrace recorded values of local variables it would be extremely slow. Even now, with these limitations in place, it can affect seriously performance of monitored applications.

I think that it is an important drawback of IntelliTrace. There are historic debuggers for other high level technologies that do not have these kind of limitations. For example Chronon for Java.

At the end, it is worth saying that IntelliTrace can record:

1. Values of parameters.
2. Values returned from methods.

However, here are also some limitations i.e.:

1. IntelliTrace will record only values of parameters that are primitive data types.
2. In the case of reference types (classes) IntelliTrace will record only values of fields/properties that that are primitive data types.
3. In the case of reference types (classes) IntelliTrace does not analyse the object graph.

Comment: but its not showing any parameters either. Where does it show these parameters, in "Locals (Historical Debugging)" windows? That windows is empty with no entires at all

Comment: Yes, you should see it in Locals window. Also in Autos window. Could you share your collection plan? Maybe the configuration is a problem.

Comment: how to share it? When I try to add it in my question, i get an error that it exceeds limit of body

Comment: By the way, can you also shareware the log? Is it confidential?

Comment: i haven't modified anything. Its the default trace that comes with standalone collector